# How to find webrick bugs in NetBeans for Ror?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, netbeans, webrick, server-error

I'm starting my adventure with Ruby on Rails and as IDE I choose Netbeans. It has bundled server Webrick and it had worked good. But after some changes in my first application it gives me internal error 500 - but nothing shows in console. And older actions give the same result.

How can I find where the problem is?
I work on Ubuntu system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can also do is add the following line to your controller "application.rb":

```
ActiveRecord::Base.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)
```

Then you will get debugging output in WEBrick's "Output" window within Netbeans.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to always have a terminal window open and to issue the follow

```
tail -f log/development.log
```

This will give you a real time, syntax colored feed of your log as you're working with your application.

Answer (score 0):

Answered myself - logs/development.log